# 'TracerExporter' not showing in the logs

Tags: open-telemetry-collector

I'm following [Istio + Loki tutorial](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/telemetry-api/) everything works fine but then I've tried to add Grafana Tempo to receive the traces and it's not working, have tried different configuration and realised the 'TracerExporter' is not showing in the logs, I guess I'm doing something wrong in the *opentelemetry-collector-contrib configMap*, appreciate any help, following configuration.

ConfigMap - opentelemetry-collector-conf

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  opentelemetry-collector-config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:
    processors:
      batch:
      attributes:
        actions:
        - action: insert
          key: loki.attribute.labels
          value: pod, namespace,cluster,mesh,hostname
    exporters:
      loki:
        endpoint: "http://loki.istio-system.svc:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
      logging:
        loglevel: debug
      jaeger:
        endpoint: jaeger-collector.istio-system.svc:14250
        tls:
          insecure: true
      otlp:
        endpoint: tempo.istio-system.svc:4317
        tls:
          insecure: true

      prometheusremotewrite:
        endpoint: http://prometheus.istio-system.svc.cluster.local:9090
        target_info:
          enabled: false

    extensions:
      health_check:
    service:
      extensions:
      - health_check
      pipelines:

        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [prometheusremotewrite]

        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: []
          exporters: [jaeger, otlp]
        logs:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [attributes, batch]
          exporters: [loki, logging]
kind: ConfigMap
```

*kubectl logs -l app=opentelemetry-collector -n istio-system -f*

```
2023-10-21T21:46:53.525Z    info    LogsExporter    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "logging", "#logs": 1}
2023-10-21T21:46:53.525Z    info    ResourceLog #0
Resource SchemaURL:
ScopeLogs #0
ScopeLogs SchemaURL:
InstrumentationScope
LogRecord #0
ObservedTimestamp: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
Timestamp: 2023-10-21 21:46:52.845122 +0000 UTC
SeverityText:
SeverityNumber: Unspecified(0)
Body: Str([2023-10-21T21:46:52.845Z] "GET /api/people HTTP/1.1" 401 - via_upstream - "-" 497 175 15 11 "10.42.0.1" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.3" "5041b7e0-5825-9bd3-8e53-fabe997464ef" "spendingbetter.com" "10.42.2.189:8082" inbound|8082|| 127.0.0.6:35567 10.42.2.189:8082 10.42.0.1:0 - default
)
Attributes:
     -> cluster: Str(Kubernetes)
     -> hostname: Str(person-service-795ffff75c-nxpgp)
     -> mesh: Str(cluster.local)
     -> namespace: Str(default)
     -> pod: Str(person-service-795ffff75c-nxpgp)
     -> status: Str(401)
     -> traceId: Str(35b97f83f739fd05c1908f2e134b2ae3)
     -> loki.attribute.labels: Str(pod, namespace,cluster,mesh,hostname)
Trace ID:
Span ID:
Flags: 0
    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "logs", "name": "logging"}
```

Loki works fine
[image]

No traces exported for Tempo
[image]